# Error due to .NET 7 Project Reunion and WinUI 3?

Tags: c#, winui-3

I am trying to use .net 7 in a win ui 3 app which still ships as the default sdk being .net 5 when I try to compile I get the following error.

It seems silly the templates still from file new run with .net 5?

```
Error   NU1202  Package 
Microsoft.ProjectReunion.InteractiveExperiences 0.8.12 
is not compatible with net7.0 
(.NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0) / win10-arm64. Package 
Microsoft.ProjectReunion.InteractiveExperiences 0.8.12 
does not support any target frameworks. SalesOrder
```

[image]

csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
    <RootNamespace>SalesOrder</RootNamespace>
    <ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
    <Platforms>x86;x64;arm64</Platforms>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x86;win10-x64;win10-arm64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <UseWinUI>true</UseWinUI>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ProjectReunion" Version="0.8.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ProjectReunion.Foundation" Version="0.8.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ProjectReunion.WinUI" Version="0.8.12" />
    <Manifest Include="$(ApplicationManifest)" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Vs Version info
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Project Reunion is stuck in .NET 5 and doesn't support.NET 7. You need to drop Project Reunion and use WinAppSDK instead.

> Visual Studio 2019 and .NET 5 is no longer supported for building C# apps (see Windows App SDK 1.2 moving to C# WinRT 2.0). You will need Visual Studio 2022 and one of the following .NET SDK versions: 6.0.401 (or later), 6.0.304, 6.0.109. When released, WinAppSDK 1.2 will support .NET 7 as well.

[WinAppSDK Release Notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/stable-channel#version-12-stable)

Comment: Im in 2022 not 2019 why has the template not been updated to reflect this seems dafe

Comment: Never mind see what I did wrong there was project reunion extension still enabled and I picked its project type by accident.